# spresenseによる加速度センサ測定とモーション認識について

Tags: spresense

https://www.switch-science.com/catalog/5258/
SPRESENSE用3軸加速度・3軸ジャイロ・気圧・温度センサ アドオンボード BMP280 BMI160搭載
が現在どこでも販売されていません。
是非購入したいのですが、無理でしょうか？
2022のサードパーティー製Add-onボードにも記載されていませんでした。
書籍にあります、加速度センサによりモーション認識を行う場合、上記購入できない場合には、どのような仕様の加速度センサを接続できて、プログラムする必要がありますでしょうか？
ご意見お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

リンク先の製品は以下二つのセンサが搭載されているようです。

- BMI160（3軸加速度・3軸ジャイロ）
- BMP280（気圧・温度センサ）

気圧・温度センサが不要なのであれば、"BMI160" で検索すればよさそうです。

Amazon で検索するだけでも複数出てきますが (6軸対応のものが多い)、3軸なら例えば以下の製品など。

**例:**
[GY-BMI160 加速度計重力センサー3軸ジャイロ+3軸加速度計ジャイロスコープセンサーモジュール (Amazon.co.jp)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B09P8L84MW/)

ピン配置の順番などは製品によって異なる可能性があるのでよく確認してください。

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございます。確認してみます。